# Kolmogorov – Filter Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, filter

Hy

I need to use this Kolmogorov filter in an apllication. You put it some measured data and with the filter it gets some hoe smoothed.
I tryed to do it with "nchoosek" however when I try to do this for an I of 50 or more it takes way too long.

[image]

Does someone know how to do this in a faster way?

```
function [ filterd ] = kolmo(data, inter)
temp  = 0;
temp1 = 0;
filterd(1:10, 1) = NaN;

for t=inter+1:(length(data)-inter)
   for o=-inter:inter
    temp = temp + (nchoosek(2*inter, (inter+o))*data(t+o));

    temp1 = temp1 + nchoosek(2*inter, (inter+o));
   end

 filterd(t, 1) = temp/temp1;
 temp  = 0;
 temp1 = 0;
end

end
```

Thx
Andy

Comment: Well, if this is about optimizing code, posting the code might be a good idea.

Comment: is this a function that gets called often in your code? and when it does, is `I` always the same?

Comment: First thing to do would be to eliminate one of the two identical calls to `nchoosek(2*inter, (inter+o))` in the inner loop.

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove any loops, and to ensure that each factorial calculation is only performed once. I would guess it is pretty close to optimal at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a loop-less solution:

```
function y = MySoln(x, K)

%# Get the binomial coefficient terms
FacAll = factorial(0:1:2*K)';
BinCoefAll = FacAll(end) ./ (FacAll .* flipud(FacAll));

%# Get all numerator terms
NumerAll = conv(x, BinCoefAll, 'valid');

%# Rescale numerator terms into output
y = (1 / sum(BinCoefAll)) * NumerAll;
```

I've avoided using `nchoosek` and instead have calculated the binomial coefficients manually using the factorials. This ensures that each factorial calculation is only performed once. In contrast, the OP's solution potentially performs each factorial calculation hundreds of times.

Once the binomial coefficients are calculated, the solution from there is a straightforward application of `conv`, and then scale by the denominator term.

I did a quick speed test between the OP solution and my solution. The speed test uses a random vector `x` with 50 elements, and sets `K` to 5. Then I run `100` iterations over my solution versus the OP solution. Here are the results:

```
Elapsed time is 2.637597 seconds. %# OP Solution
Elapsed time is 0.010401 seconds. %# My Solution
```

I'm pretty happy with this. I doubt the method can be made much more efficient from this point (but would be happy to be proven wrong). :-)